# Unable to use IIS7 with Visual Studio 2010, MVC2.0 and NET4

Tags: visual-studio-2010, iis-7, windows-7, asp.net-mvc-2, asp.net-4.0

Here is my environment
Windows7, Visual Studio 2010, MVC2.0 and NET4
My default web site is configured to use ASP.NET v4.0 application pool.

Here is an easy way to reproduce my problem

Create a new MVC2 application 
Open the properties Window
Go to the Web tab
Check "Use IIS Local Web Server"
Click on "Create Virtual Directory" button

I get this error message

```
To access local IIS Web Sites, you must install the following IIS components:

In addition, you must run visual Studio in the context of an Administrator account
For more information, press F1
```

Notice the blank line after "...the following IIS components:"

I am running VS2010 as administrator
Pressing F1 does not bring any help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I checked my Windows eventlog files and found that my metabase was corrupted
(I thought we get rid of this in IIS7 but it looks like it is still here...)

I used this [Microsoft article](http://www.microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/WindowsServer2003/Library/IIS/1ddc4ce8-0e98-4063-9776-cc400e713cb5.mspx?mfr=true) to restore it from an old version and now everything is working

Hope this can help somebody else

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried running VS as administrator?

Right click your VS shortcut and select "Run as Administrator"

Comment: That's the case
I am running it as Administrator
I just realized that my IIS is 7.5  (7.5.7600.16385) instead of 7.0

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error message, in my case with VS2008, Windows 7 + IIS7, when trying to add an existing web site to a solution. I think this is one of those error messages where what it states can be a big red herring, i.e. it doesn't necessarily have anything to do with running as an administrator or not having components installed.

In my case, the web site had an HTTP binding in which the hostname was set to "localhost". Once I cleared that, it worked fine. Don't ask me why I put "localhost" in there, it just seemed to make sense at the time.

My internet hunting also turned up [this brief entry](http://www.drowningintechnicaldebt.com/ShawnWeisfeld/archive/2010/04/12/cannot-open-iis-based-websites-in-vs.net-2008.aspx), which did not work for me.